# no apt package "atom" .but there is a snap with that name

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, snap, purge

I installed Atom. Then I removed it with `sudo apt-get remove atom` command. Now when I tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge atom`, it shows  `no apt package atom`, but there is a snap with that name.

How to remove that snap?

Comment: I did `sudo snap remove atom`. And that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The atom package that was installed by `sudo apt install atom` has already been removed, which is the reason why you got the following error message:

```
No apt package "atom", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install atom"

E: Unable to locate package atom
```